# Parsing of array from JSON string in Redis not working correctly

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

I am working with a redis database trying to retrieve an array previously saved as a JSON string to a new Array of arrays. My code is:

```
    data = Hash.new 
    data["columns"] = Array.new

    redis.keys("search_string").each do |key|
        set_data = redis.hmget(key, "data")
        puts set_data.class
        data["columns"].push(set_data)
    end

    puts "Data is #{data["columns"]}"
```

The data element on the redis hash set is stored using the code

```
    redis.hmset("myKey", "data", data_array.to_json)
```

The first piece of code seems to be adding an extra Array in and calling JSON.parse(set_data) returns an error "no implicit conversion of array into string". The output of the puts are as follows:

```
 | Array
 | Data is [["[\"Accounts\",7]"]]
```

Which seems that there is an extra array in the data structure. Any suggestions on how I can get my output to be

```
 Data is [["Accounts", 7]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing an `Array` containing json string representations of `Array`s into an `Array` thus your result has an additional level. You could use

```
 data["columns"].push(set_data.map{|e| JSON.parse(e)}.flatten)
 #=>[["Accounts",7]]
```

Or skip the initial `Array.new` and use

```
 data["columns"] = set_data.map{|e| JSON.parse(e)}
 #=>[["Accounts",7]]
```

Also is there a reason that you want data to be an `Array` of `Array`s why not just have it be the actual `set_data` `Array` like this

```
 data["columns"] = set_data.map{|e| JSON.parse(e)}.flatten
 #=>["Accounts",7]
```

Comment: I need an array of arrays for it to be passed onto a separate system. Your top line solved the problem perfectly, thanks.